# What is the performance of bag_unpack in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

### Some questions regarding the performance and use of `bag_unpack` in Kusto:

- How performant is using `bag_unpack` over a large data set on a column
  where all the top-level properties *are the same* (so each row has a
  dynamic bag with the same property name so each resulting column from
  the bag unpack would have a value)?
- How performant is using `bag_unpack` over a large data set on a column
  where the top-level properties are *not all the same*, so not garaunteed to
  have the same top-level properties (so there will be some rows where the
  unpacked columns have empty/no value)?
- Does bag_unpack use any methods that are considered slow in terms of
  performance like `extract_json()` or `parse_json()`, or is it much quicker than those methods?

Given the following two examples, which is more optimized or would execute faster for a large dataset? (or would they be about the same?):

```
//#1
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"Name": "John", "Age":20}),
    dynamic({"Name": "Dave", "Age":40}),
    dynamic({"Name": "Jasmine", "Age":30}),
]
| evaluate bag_unpack(d)
```

```
//#2
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"Name": "John", "Age":20}),
    dynamic({"Name": "Dave", "Age":40}),
    dynamic({"Name": "Jasmine", "Age":30}),
]
| project Age = d.Age, Name = d.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is always preferred.

When the set of properties you wish to project is known in advance, it would be more performant to explicitly project only those, and not use the `bag_unpack()` plugin. **(*)**

The latter requires 2 passes over the data -

1. For building the output schema (by analyzing which properties exist in the dynamic payloads across all queried records).

   - This is done similarly to how the [`buildschema` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/buildschema-aggfunction) operates.
2. Executing the query with the now-known output schema.

---

**(*)** Asides for performance, this has the advantage of the output schema always being stable, which may be required by some automated scenarios - even in case the source data changes, and there are new properties added to the dynamic payload (or old ones removed), that won't affect the output schema.